# Retrieve values from related table foreign key using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Sorry if the question isn't clear.. I'm not super fluent in databases.

I have three tables:

```
 companies       equipment          parts
-----------     -----------      -----------
id               id               id
name             company_id       equipment_id
```

Using Eloquent, how do I get a `Collection` of all the parts that belong to the company with id=1

I know you setup relationships in the model. So now I can get all a company's equipment (`$myCompany->equipment`), and all equipment's parts (`$myEquipment->parts`), but I'm not sure how to easily get values in the reverse direction two tables away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has such a beautiful documentation and API for this very thing. Take a look at the [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

So in your Company model add this:

```
/**
 * Get all of the parts for the company.
 */
public function parts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Part', 'App\Equipment');
}
```

Comment: @Sandy glad it helped, please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: I've considered it and the outcome is positive.